# How do I strip combination of numbers and period in string in python?

Tags: python, replace, strip

I have a column with strings that look like below. They are combination of IP Address and system name. 
I want to strip the IP address part of the string, which is everything before the first hyphen.

```
str = "12.345.678.9-abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567"
```

So far, I've tried below,

```
str.replace('\D+', '') 
str.lstrip('\D+', '')
str.rstrip('\D+', '')
```

'I want to delete everything until the first hyphen.' This sounds like a simple task but I'm experiencing a learning curve. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your strings are formatted in that same way, you could just split the string on the hyphen using the `str.split()` method, remove the first item of the resulting list, and then use the `str.join()` method to combine it again like so:

```
string = "12.345.678.9-abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567".split("-")[1:]
>>> ['abcd1_0', 'def', 'ghi', '4567']
joined_str = "-".join(string)
>>> abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567
```

Comment: Worked pretty well with str.split() method. Below is what I used.
df['ID'].str.split('-',1).str[1]

Other option was,
df['ID']=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.lstrip('0123456789.-')))

Answer (score 0):

You can [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) the first `'-'` and then take a slice from that point on:

```
>>> s = '12.345.678.9-abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567'
>>> s[s.find('-')+1:]
'abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    import re
    m = re.search('\d+-(.*)', s).group(1)

You get
    'abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567'

Answer (score 0):

A regex-based solution to the collection:

```
re.findall(r'[^-]+-(.+)',s)[0]
#'abcd1_0-def-ghi-4567'
```